# Why does create-react-app based app with react-router v6 crashes on mobile?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, create-react-app

I have following problem: I added react router to my create-react-app, since I have to use gyroscope api I wanted to test my changes on mobile device. I am accessing app on mobile via local network and it renders blank page. At first I thought that there is a network issue but app works correctly when router is not used.

I tried both `BrowserRouter` and `HashRouter` but it didn't help. Here is console error:
[console errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSJbX.jpg)
since it is not very descriptive I tried wrapping up render into try catch block:
[trycatch block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLgO2.png)
but error message remains the same.

```
"react-router-dom": "^6.4.3"
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0"
```

Do you guys have any idea what is going on? I will be extremely grateful for help.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html

Comment: Thank you, turned out that I have some ReferenceError. I thought that it will be logged to the console.